# Custom meta_query order for Elementor based on post meta key

Tags: wp-query, filters, meta-query

I'm failing at writing an Elementor `$meta_query` function so posts will be ordered by `meta_value_num` of a given key.

Each post has a numeric value for the key `google_unique_page_views`

My example is below:

```
// Custom query to order 'recommended reading' posts by populatrity
add_action( 'elementor/query/my_custom_filter', function( $query ) {
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    }
    $meta_query[] = [
        'order'=> 'DESC',
        'key' => 'google_unique_page_views',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    ];
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );   
});
```

Do I need to include the `value` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get posts with that meta key, regardless of content, and order by that meta value, you would need to set two properties.

1. meta_query
2. orderby

So the code, based of your question would be like this

```php
// Custom query to order 'recommended reading' posts by populatrity
add_action('elementor/query/my_custom_filter', function ($query) {
    if (empty($meta_query = $query->get('meta_query'))) $meta_query = [];

    // add our condition to the meta_query
    $meta_query['google_unique_page_views'] = [
        'key'     => 'google_unique_page_views',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ];

    // set the new meta_query
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

    // set the new orderby
    $query->set('orderby', [
        'google_unique_page_views' => 'DESC' // or ASC, based on your needs
    ]);
});
```

Comment: That works perfect thanks! Had to make one tweak to `orderby` (replace `google_unique_page_views` with `meta_value_num`) to make it work super good. Thanks again